# F#: multiple string splits

Tags: f#

This works:

```
let string = "Items: 79, 98"
let parts = string.Split(":")[1]
let items = parts.Split(", ")
```

Giving a string array of `[|" 79"; "98"|]`. However this doesn't work:

```
let string = "Items: 79, 98"
let items = string.Split(":")[1].Split(", ")
```

Raising `error FS0597: Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized`.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error usually appears when there's something not right with the syntax of the invocation of a function. Note that the `[]` operator was introduced in F# 6.0, so if you use older version of the language, you will have to use `.[]`.
This syntax works:

```ml
let string = "Items: 79, 98"
let items2 = string.Split(":").[1].Split(", ")
printfn "%A" items2
```

More information on this topic:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-fsharp-6/#making-f-simpler-to-learn-indexing-with-expridx

**EDIT:** Having said the above, this issue looks like a parser bug. Your code uses the new syntax already in your first example.